# Не получается запрос

Tags: sql, firebird

Доброе время суток, есть запрос:

```
select * from ARCHIVE where '30.01.2017' = (cast(DATE_END as date)) and (SUM_RESULT < 0 or SUM_RESULT > 0)
```

Которым я вывожу данные за указанную дату, но мне нужно не данные, а количество строк `(SUM_RESULT) < 0  (SUM_RESULT > 0)`

Пробовал через `case`,  `count`, но толком ни чего не получилось.
Проблема с группировкой:

> «Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).»

Спасибо

Comment: Просто задайте `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`

Comment: каким именно образом `count()` используете?

Comment: SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUM_RESULT>=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Positive,
    SUM(CASE WHEN SUM_RESULT<0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Negative
  FROM ARCHIVE
where '30.01.2017' = (cast(DATE_END_RATE as date))    (*извиняюсь за редактирование) - точнее просто "0" - выдает

Comment: это `case`, а `count`?

Comment: @Konstantin78 пробовали выбрать `select * from ...` записи вообще в таблице есть с подходящими значениями?

Comment: я поторопился, и там вместо "count", я просто пробую считать "1" через "Sum"

Comment: @ Vitaly Kolyada, конечно, запрос в моем "вопросе" - работает, и выдает нужные записи, осталось вместо них получить их количество с положительными и отрицательными значениями.

Comment: @Konstantin78 вы можете сказать какой тип у поля `SUM_RESULT`, а еще лучше привести пример любой записи в вашей таблице

Comment: тип поля "Double precision". Сейчас попробую переставить firebird, потому что у меня появились ЧАСТЬ запросов, которые раньше работали, а теперь нет. Запрос должен работать с 'SUM'